# AC unit won't turn on: both inside blower fan and outside fan unit won't turn on

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, central-air

AC unit won't turn on: both inside blower fan and outside fan unit won't turn on. It is as if I had gone to the circuit breaker and cut the power to the whole HVAC system, but I didn't. I've been searching around and saw that in most cases, either the inside or the outside unit won't turn on, but I have not found a case where both won't turn on.

The outside unit has a disconnect box that contains no fuse. I've double checked that the rabbits didn't somehow manage to take the connector piece out...

I've also replaced the old mercury-based thermostat with a new digital, battery-powered thermostat, which didn't help. I can hear the clicking sound it makes to turn on the AC, but nothing else happens.

It was working fine 5 days ago. I turned it off for 5 days straight, and now it won't turn on again.

I'm trying to get an HVAC pro to come and take a look, but they're booked until next week. Is there anything else I can check in the mean time?

EDIT:
I'd like to open up the access control panel to check for fuse locations, but I cannot figure out how to do so. Here's a picture of what I assume to be the panel door. I've tried prying it open from all 4 sides with a flathead driver. It also doesn't slide in any direction. Any suggestion?

[image: access control panel door]

Additionally, I've verified that there is electricity in the unit. There is voltage in that the exterior white wire going from the box to the thermostat (see picture) and there's also voltage going through the disconnect box and into the outside fan unit...

UPDATE2:

I was able to take the control panel door off, and found that it's getting no electricity. As you can see in pic1, the exterior white wire is live and it goes in the little box with the black push switch to the left of the picture. However, in pic2 the three internal wires (green, white, and black) going out of the box are not live.

Pic1 - electricity going into the little box

[image]

Pic2 - no electricity going out of the little box

[image]

Additionally, the red status light that used to be on all the time (which I didn't recall till now) is now off.

Pic3: red status light no longer on.

[image]

So what is this little box and could it be the cause?

[image]

Comment: Do you have a volt meter or multimeter?  Are you comfortable poking around in the HVAC equipment?

Comment: Do you have a furnace, or air handler? If you have a furnace, does the heat work?

Comment: I don't have a meter... but I will pick one up this evening. I have a furnace, although it's currently too hot (~90 F) for the heater to come on.

Comment: Did you check the breakers to make sure they're not tripped? Sometimes when they trip, they don't move all the way to the OFF position, so they can appear to be ON.

Comment: Thanks, I've flipped the breaker switch off and on several times to no effect. I've called the tech and they'll come next week to diagnose the problem. I'll report back what the problem is.

Comment: There could be fuses in the air handler/furnace that are blown, or the transformer could have died. If you open the unit up, there should be a schematic. The schematic will show you if there are fuses, and give you an idea of where they are.

Comment: @Tester101 I would like to open it up and view the schematic, but cannot manage to do so. I've updated my question with a picture of the access control panel door, could you please have a look? Thank you!

Comment: You probably have to take the upper panel off first. Typically it will lift up a bit, then the bottom of the panel will come out.  Then you'll do the same to remove the bottom panel, lift it up a bit then it should come off.

Comment: If that doesn't work, include the exact make and model, and I'll look it up.

Comment: Ah, I had thought about removing the top panel, but it covers the gas pumps so I thought it was off limit. I will give that a try when I get home later today. Regarding the make and model, I WISH I knew... there's one tiny little label above the top panel that probably has that info, but it got partially burned off (something shady happened there).

Comment: The model number should also be listed on a plate inside the unit.  **WARNING:** Don't run the unit with the covers off, unless you're a trained professional and/or know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. I'll take a picture of the board inside and post it up here. Hopefully the fuse location along with the make/model names will be obvious.

Comment: @Tester101 I've updated my question with new pictures. It looks like the problem is that there is no electricity going to the control board...

Comment: Uhh, well, in doing all of this, I've found the answer to my own question - the box is a safety measure which cuts the electricity when the panel door is removed. Turns out, there were a couple of screws on the outside that secure this box that were missing. Why? Me. I removed them a few days back when trying to open this panel door so that I can do the "G wire to C wire" switch for a new thermostat. Well, put those back and it's working now :)

Comment: Check your filter. It's hard to tell from the photo, but it looks like it might be dirty.

Comment: That unit is a bowl of spaghetti for a homeowner to be expected to work on this while hot, potentially lethal situation where 1 error may be the last you make is not something I recommend you attempting. this units wiring while not bad is not user friendly and power sure isn't

Comment: I don't know if it's just me or this looks like the furnace with an acoil inside, you said a/c in which if it was me I'd start with the capacitors in the unit itself after shutting off the A/C unit inside and out, if there's 2 for safety precautions Your fix is helpful, I didn't know that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turns out, the box in the last picture is a safety measure which cuts the electricity when the panel door is removed. Turns out, there were a couple of screws on the outside that secure this box that were missing. Why? I did it (DOH!). I removed them a few days back when trying to open this panel door so that I can do the "G wire to C wire" switch for a new thermostat. Well, put those back and it's working now.

Comment: Glad you figured it out, you probably saved yourself a couple hundred bucks, and an embarrassing service visit.